# how to club as 1 record if employee has worked continuously

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

how to club as 1 record if employee has worked continuously from feb 1 to feb 15th.
please help me

### example

scenario 1.emp who has worked continuously.

```
   empid datebegin  dateend

    1     2017-02-01  2017-02-05

    1     2017-02-06  2017-02-08

    1     2017-02-09  2017-02-15
```

desired O/P: 1 2017-02-01  2017-02-15

scenario2:not worked continuously

empid datebegin  dateend

```
    1     2017-02-01  2017-02-05

    1     2017-02-07  2017-02-08

    1     2017-02-09  2017-02-15
```

desired O/P:
empid datebegin  dateend

```
    1     2017-02-01  2017-02-05

    1     2017-02-07  2017-02-15
```

Comment: ,What is your expected output..?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far ?

Comment: You should also add an example where an employee has NOT worked continuously to clarify your question.

Comment: below are the example where emp has not worked on 6th

empid datebegin  dateend

1     2017-02-01  2017-02-05
1     2017-02-07  2017-02-10

Comment: No. Edit your question. Show sample data for an employee who has worked continuously and another who hasn't. Then show the result the query shall produce for the two employees.

Comment: Ah, Gaps and Islands.  A little tricky those.

Answer (score 0):

Use MAX and MIN aggregate funtcions :

```
 CREATE TABLE #Table(empid INT, datebegin DATE , dateend DATE)

 INSERT INTO #Table( empid , datebegin , dateend)
 SELECT 1,'2017-02-01','2017-02-05' UNION ALL
 SELECT 1,'2017-02-06','2017-02-08' UNION ALL
 SELECT 1,'2017-02-09','2017-02-15' 

 SELECT empid , MIN(datebegin) datebegin ,MAX(dateend) dateend
 FROM #Table
 GROUP BY empid
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but if the emp has not worked continuously we dont want to club it as 1 record

Answer (score 0):

Using a Common table expression and ROW_NUmber this is possible like so

```
DECLARE @sample TABLE (empid INT, datebegin DATE, dateend DATE )
INSERT INTO @sample
 (  empid, datebegin, dateend ) 
VALUES
(1,'2017-02-01','2017-02-05' )
,(1,'2017-02-06','2017-02-08' )
,(1,'2017-02-09','2017-02-15' )
,(2,'2017-02-01','2017-02-05' )
,(2,'2017-02-07','2017-02-08' )
,(2,'2017-02-09','2017-02-15' )

;WITH cteX
AS(
    SELECT
          ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY S.empid, S.datebegin) 'RN'
        , S.empid
        , S.datebegin
        , S.dateend
    FROM @sample S
)
SELECT
    S.RN
  , S.empid
  , S.datebegin
  , S.dateend
  , DATEDIFF(DAY,S.dateend, S1.datebegin ) 'Diff'
  , S1.datebegin
  , S1.dateend
FROM cteX S
 JOIN
    cteX S1 ON S1.empid = S.empid AND S1.RN = S.RN + 1
ORDER BY S.RN
```

produces following output

```
empid   datebegin   dateend
1   2017-02-01  2017-02-15
2   2017-02-01  2017-02-05
2   2017-02-07  2017-02-15
```